# Guarding your Eyes, or your Mouth, which is most important?

Tags: zohar

Kav ha-Yashar says one should guard their eyes, that's important, though guarding your tongue, is most important. Why? Because your eyes only protects ***your*** soul, while guarding your mouth is ***guarding two souls***, your soul and that of your brothers and sisters.

I recall a shiure, they mentioned a certain Kabbalist (It may be Rabbi shimon baryochay) who asked why we don't have two mouths, one for learning and one for talking / eating, he was answered with something along the lines of, one does enough damage, or, can you control just one mouth.

That is all great,

Though the great rabbis and or Mystics will easily promote guarding the eyes over your mouth. The question is why, why are they more concerned with the eyes than the mouth. Looking at Baba Elazzar Abuchatzera, who had a tunnel just to protect his eyes, and he's just one from the many in his family and the families alike.

You don't see them doing ta-anit dibure none stop, or anything of the like, so what is going on? Which is the real deal, guarding your eyes or your mouth.

Comment: It's harder to guard one's eyes in the sense that your vision works automatically. So Rabbi Abuchazzera is worried that something may come into his field of view. But for guarding his mouth, he just needs to be careful with his own speech, which I'm sure he is.

Comment: Guard your eyes. The eye sees and the heart desires. It doesn't say, the mouth speaks and the heart desires. You can keep the mouth closed by choice but cant function as a human for long, by keeping your eyes shut. Side note: I used to not wear contacts during summer time, when there was a higher probability of seeing immodest people. I had a hard time catching any detail of someone on the street without contacts. ( Yea Yea thinly veiled self righteousness brag post LOL)

Comment: @MarsSojourner, Yes though a desire may be for good, like your words. You can gear your eyes away, like you can stop your words, you may see "things" just like you may "say" things, it's all the same. So what makes one thing better than the other?